# MPI_Scatter allocation for float - MPI,C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm starting out in MPI. For the homework i'm doing i need produce sum of an input we specify by allocating jobs to different process. My program works fine when I get integer results. e.g 20/20 = 1 or 20/10 = 2. however when I get decimal points 20/9 =2.222, I get into trouble and get wrong results. I'm not quite sure how to get around this. Here is my code for Scattering and producing sum.

> where  readNumber = value read in (e.g 20) storage = array with values
>   (1,2,3,4....20)

```
/*Scatter*/ 
    MPI_Scatter(storage, readNumber/size, MPI_INT, 

                         recStorage, readNumber/size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    total=0;
    printf("%d \n",readNumber/size);
    for(i=0;i<readNumber/size;i++){
        total=total+recStorage[i];
    }
    printf("rank= %d total= %d \n ",rank,total);


    /*Reduce*/

    MPI_Reduce( &total, &gtotal, send_count, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0,   MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if(rank == 0){
      printf("total = %d \n ",gtotal);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use MPI_FLOAT for the type argument in both scatter and reduce if you want to get float result.

EDIT: also if you want to get floating point result do not use %d in printf.

SECOND EDIT: after clarification about the answer. You can not use non-integer number of elements neither for the sent nor the received elements. Take a look [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatter.html).

THIRD_EDIT: you can handle sending non-equal number of elements to each processor. Take a look at [MPI_Scatterv](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Scatterv.3.php)

Comment: Thanks. Isn't issue with allocating jobs for each process. Would doing this solve this? Is it possible to assign 2.22 jobs to a processor? I tried your suggestions, of making variables of type int into type float however this is giving me very wrong output.

Comment: Oh... I did not get your question at all. Thought you are asking of the summing result. I do not think you can use non-integer number of jobs. Try to make your jobs smaller.

Comment: It is not possible to assign 2.22 jobs to a processor.

Comment: I was hoping to somehow get around this. The problem is, I have to check results of very high number of jobs(>1000). I guess the only option now is to say if readNumber/size = float, then say the job can't be done.

Comment: @user1323232 no the job can be done - you just need to use scatterv. Take a look at my last edit.

Comment: @izomorphius: +1 for a good solution, -1 for too much help with homework.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I don't get what do you mean by too much help. I only mentioned the function he(she) needs... Couldn't have been less detailed.

Comment: Thankyou. As I said, I'm new with MPI, so still getting into grips with this. I'm trying this right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to send equal sized parcels of work to each process, even when the number of processes is not a divisor of the amount of work.  I mean, if you want to sum the elements of a 2000 element array, then each of 4 processors would get 500 elements, each of 9 processors would get, ... err hang on ... in integer division `2000/9 = 222` but `9*222==1998` and if you don't take care 2 elements of your array will not get added into the sum.  You'll have to make arrangements to have those elements allocated to processes.

Since this is your homework I'll leave the details to you.